# Data not updating in style binding (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to reactively set the height of a wrapper div using data in Vue. The data is set when all the children of the wrapper div is loaded and is then set to the totalt height of all of them added together. Basically I want the wrapper to have a fixed pixel value in CSS based on the height of all of its children combined.

I use `watch` to set the height after the content from the database has been loaded. `post` in the code below is the array from the database that contains the data of the post that the current component should render from.

```
watch: {
        post(){
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.setTotalHeight();
            })
        }
    }
```

The `setTotalHeight()` method looks like this:

```
setTotalHeight() {
            this.totalHeight = this.$refs.top.offsetHeight + this.$refs.middle.offsetHeight + this.$refs.bottom.offsetHeight
        }
```

I also trigger the `setTotalHeight()` method on resize.

When these functions has run, the `totalHeight` data value is set to the number that the calculation in `setTotalHeight()` equals to. I can see the value if I look in the dev tools, and if I output the value with `{{totalHeight}}` in the "DOM", I can see it with the correct value.

However, when I try to apply this value to the wrapper div by doing `:style="{height: totalHeight}"`, it's not updating. I initially set the `totalHeight` data value to `0`, and this is what the style is being set to without ever changing.

Am I doing something wrong with this or why is the style binding not updating when the data itself is updating and the output in the "DOM" with `{{totalHeight}}` is updating accordingly? Is style binding not reactive or what might be causing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its just like you are setting a CSS height proprety with no unit `height : 1000`

you need to add the unit after the height on the style binding (`px`/`em`...etc) like:

```
<wrapper :style="{height: totalHeight +'px'}" </wrapper>
```

Comment: I saw that you commented first, so the correct answer point goes to you. :)
Like I mentioned above though, `totalHeight` is set to `0` as a `Number` from the start, and that showed up as `<div style="height: 0px;">` in the rendered HTML, with the "px" added. So it seems like Vue adds the "px" automatically but doesn't update the value in a reactive way. The style seems to only become reactive if you add the "px" manually.

Comment: Yes .. Actually vue does't add that automatically .... if you don't add the "px" ...any value you give to ´height´  will be coerced implicitly to "0px" cause binding a number is not a valid input and since you have bound the proprety it might be better for vue to convert that to 0 than throwing an error...And btw this was happening alot to me  .

Comment: Ah, I see! So it was just a coincidence that my intial data value was set to `0`. It would've been set to `0px` either way if I understand it correctly? Anyways, thanks for the info and for the help!

Comment: and They said Vue is easy to debug, I didn't even find a broken `height : 1000 ` in the browser development tool

Answer (score 5):

Did you add 'px' to your height value? If not, try this:

```
:style="{height:totalHeight+'px'}"
```

Comment: Hmm. I think Vue adds the ”px” automatically since the raw data value from the beginning is just a number but then shows as “0px” in the inline style of the element in my case. But I’ll try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem here moments ago and it ended up being caused by applying a class while applying a conflicting style:

```
<div class="flex-1" :style="{ height: '800px' }">
```

That failed because flex-1 caused the explicit height to be ignored. After removing `flex-1` it worked as expected and is reactive.

Be careful about that if you find similar issue.